# Hardware Enter key opens DrawerLayout (unnecessarily)

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I'm working on an app that handles barcode reads, and returns the product information that belongs to the barcode.

On one of my fragments, i have a EditText, you can either manually type the barcode, or use a reader, if the textbox gets and ENTER keydown, it starts the data requests, this works fine.

Here is my problem, i have an other fragment, but this one doesn't have a EditText, and i do not wish to add one, but i still wish to handle the barcode request.

The way i solved it, this belongs to the MainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        Log.v("MainActivity: ", "Enter");
        return true;
    }
    char unicodechar = (char)event.getUnicodeChar();
    Log.v("main", keyCode + " - " + unicodechar) ;
    Long timedifference = elapsedRealtime() - PreviousTime;
    if (timedifference > MIN_RESPONSE_TIME && Vonalkód.length() == 0) {
        Vonalkód.append(unicodechar);
    }
    if (timedifference < MIN_RESPONSE_TIME && Vonalkód.length() > 0) {
        Vonalkód.append(unicodechar);
    }

    cdt = new CountDownTimer(200, 20) { 
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            int tab = ((GlobalVars) getApplication()).get_activetab();
            ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            FragmentPagerAdapter fpa = (FragmentPagerAdapter) vp.getAdapter();
            if (tab == 0){ // Átvétel
                FragmentAruAtvetelMain frag = (FragmentAruAtvetelMain) fpa.instantiateItem(vp, tab);
                if (frag != null){
                    frag.myOnKeyDown(Vonalkód.toString());
                }

            }
            if (tab == 1){ // Átvételi lista
                FragmentAruAtvetelLista frag = (FragmentAruAtvetelLista) fpa.instantiateItem(vp, tab);
                if (frag != null){
                    frag.myOnKeyDown(Vonalkód.toString());
                }
            }
            Vonalkód = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }.start();

    PreviousTime = elapsedRealtime();

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

I capture the barcode reader's key presses with the MainActivity, if there isn't any new character after 200ms, i consider it done. The currently active view, is a Tablayout with 2 tabs. I know which tab is active, and i send the barcode text from the MainActivity, to the currently active fragment's method.

Here is my MainActivity's layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/half_black"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:title="KBRMobile" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/containerView">
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/NavView"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
            app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now here is my problem, if i press the ENTER key on my fragments, it opens the Drawerlayout.

This is how my debug log looks like after a barcode read

(char code - actual unicode):

```
V/main: 12 - 5
V/main: 16 - 9
V/main: 16 - 9
V/main: 14 - 7
V/main: 9 - 2
V/main: 9 - 2
V/main: 8 - 1
V/main: 14 - 7
V/main: 7 - 0
V/main: 8 - 1
V/main: 9 - 2
V/main: 9 - 2
V/main: 14 - 7
(this is where the ENTER key should be, but something "captured it", and opened the DrawerLayout)
V/Main:: 5997221701227
```

At this point the DrawerLayout is open. If i read the barcode again:

```
V/main: 12 - 5
V/main: 16 - 9
V/main: 16 - 9
V/main: 14 - 7
V/main: 9 - 2
V/main: 9 - 2
V/main: 8 - 1
V/main: 14 - 7
V/main: 7 - 0
V/main: 8 - 1
V/main: 9 - 2
V/main: 9 - 2
V/main: 14 - 7
V/MainActivity:: Enter
V/Main:: 5997221701227
```

While the DrawerLayout is open, OnKeyDown now able to get the ENTER key.

So after all this, my question is this, what captures the ENTER key even before it's reaches the MainActivity's OnKeyDown? Why the ENTER key opens the DrawerLayout, and how can i prevent this? I just want to capture the barcode with the ENTER key at it's end, so this way i could handle the barcode reading process much reliably. Currently i'm not happy with the CountDownTimer.

**UPDATE**

If you are dealing with this kinda problem, here is some tips.

What you are looking for is the: [dispatchKeyEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchKeyEvent(android.view.KeyEvent))(KeyEvent event). This method gets all the key event before it reaches the window.

You have two options:

1. requestFocus() on some gui element so they will consume the Enter key
2. Override dispatcherKeyEvent and disable the enter key in the whole activty.

Comment: If you scan a barcode that doesn't end in a seven, does the DrawerLayout still open? My guess is that since an input field isn't selected and you aren't stopping the propagation of the key presses, the numbers could be causing the focus to change and seven selects the DrawerLayout which handles the return key press by opening (and stops it from propagating). Just a guess though

Comment: I'm pretty sure, it has nothing to do with the number sequence. It's all about DrawerLayout default behavior. Exp. in Google Play, if you press Enter twice, it will open the Drawer. On the first Enter, it will highlight the "hambuger menu", and on the second, it will open the DL. I tested this on multiple apps that had DL too. Imo the reason why it's opens the DL immediately in my case, is because right now my fragment is empty, and has 0 UI controls.